# Am I setting up the useStates correctly in which these datas will be saved in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The context is that I have a product name where there will be sizes, colors, and quantities. The user can also add more sizes, color, and quantities of the same product and I will be saving this in Firestore.

**For example:**

- **Product Name: Shirt**
- **Size: Large**
- Color: Red, Qty: 10
- Color: Blue, Qty: 5
- **Size: M**
- Color: Red, Qty: 10
- Color: Blue, Qty: 5

So in the form, the user should be able to add a size, add more colors and qty.
This is what I did:
[image]

Codes:
Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-2-add-more-size-ddqqo?file=/demo.js:0-5210

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

import { TextField, Button } from "@mui/material";

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [productName, setProductName] = useState();
  const [sizeList, setSizeList] = useState([{ size: "" }]);
  const [colorList, setColorList] = useState([{ color: "", colorStocks: "" }]);

  //sizes
  const handleServiceChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...sizeList];
    list[index] = { ...list[index] }; // copy the item too
    list[index][name] = value;
    setSizeList(list);
  };

  const handleServiceRemove = (index) => {
    const list = [...sizeList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setSizeList(list);
  };

  const handleServiceAdd = () => {
    setSizeList([...sizeList, { service: "" }]);
  };

  // color
  const handleColorChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...colorList];
    list[index] = { ...list[index] }; // copy the item too
    list[index][name] = value;
    setColorList(list);
  };

  // const handleColorStocksChange = (e, index) => {
  //   const { name, value } = e.target;
  //   const list = [...colorList];
  //   list[index][name] = value;
  //   setColorList(list);
  //   // console.log(colorList);
  // };

  // const handleColorChange = (e, index) => {
  //   const { value } = e.target;

  //   const arr = [...colorList]; //Shallow copy the existing state
  //   arr[index].color = value; //Update the size to the selected size
  //   console.log(arr[index].value);
  //   setColorList([...arr]); //Set the updated array to be the new state
  // };

  // const handleColorStocksChange = (e, index) => {
  //   const { value } = e.target;
  //   console.log(value);
  //   const arr = [...colorList];
  //   arr[index].colorStocks = value;
  //   // console.log(arr)
  //   setColorList([...arr]);
  // };

  const handleColorRemove = (index) => {
    const list = [...colorList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setColorList(list);
  };

  const handleColorAdd = () => {
    setColorList([...colorList, { color: "", colorStocks: "" }]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Product: ", productName, "size: ", sizeList, colorList);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          label="Product Name"
          name="name"
          type="text"
          id="productName"
          value={productName}
          onChange={(e) => setProductName(e.target.value)}
          required
        />

        {sizeList.map((singleSize, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <TextField
              label="Size"
              type="text"
              name={`size${index}`}
              id={`size${index}`}
              required
              value={singleSize.size}
              onChange={(e) => handleServiceChange(e, index)}
            />
            {colorList.map((singleColor, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                <TextField
                  label="color"
                  name="color"
                  type="text"
                  id="color"
                  required
                  value={singleColor.color}
                  onChange={(e) => handleColorChange(e, index)}
                />
                <TextField
                  label="Stocks"
                  name="colorStocks"
                  type="text"
                  id="colorStocks"
                  required
                  value={singleColor.colorStocks}
                  onChange={(e) => handleColorChange(e, index)}
                />
                {colorList.length !== 1 && (
                  <Button onClick={() => handleColorRemove(index)}>
                    Remove
                  </Button>
                )}
                <br />
                {colorList.length - 1 === index && (
                  <Button onClick={handleColorAdd}>Add Color</Button>
                )}
                <br /> <br />
                {/* add or remove sizes */}
              </div>
            ))}
            {sizeList.length - 1 === index && (
              <Button type="button" onClick={handleServiceAdd}>
                Add size
              </Button>
            )}
            {sizeList.length - 1 === index && (
              <Button type="button" onClick={() => handleServiceRemove(index)}>
                Remove Size
              </Button>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}

        <br />
        <Button type="submit">Submit </Button>
      </form>

      <div className="output">
        <h2>Output</h2>
        <h3>Sizes:</h3>
        {sizeList &&
          sizeList.map((singleSize, index) => (
            <ul key={index}>{singleSize.size && <li>{singleSize.size}</li>}</ul>
          ))}

        <br />
        <h3>Color:</h3>
        {colorList &&
          colorList.map((singleSize, index) => (
            <ul key={index}>
              {singleSize.color && (
                <li>{singleSize.color + " - " + singleSize.colorStocks}</li>
              )}
            </ul>
          ))}
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic forms like this I like to keep all the state together so it's easy to expand/reduce the lists. It's also really important to not use mutation anywhere.

```
const colorInit = { color: "", stocks: 0 };

const init = { size: "", colors: [colorInit] };

const A = () => {
  const [sizeList, setSizeList] = useState([init]);

  const addSize = () => {
    setSizeList([...sizeList, init]);
  };

  const addColor = (i) => {
    setSizeList(
      sizeList.map((s, ii) =>
        ii === i ? { ...s, colors: [...s.colors, colorInit] } : s
      )
    );
  };

  // The other two remove from list functions

  const updateSize = (i, size) => {
    setSizeList(sizeList.map((s, ii) => (ii === i ? { ...s, size } : s)));
  };

  // The other two update functions, using immutability
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by // The other two remove from list functions? Also where could I put the `updateSize`? I'm really sorry, I'm quite confused. And also if done this way, how would the the form looked like?

Comment: I tried doing it by your example and I'm getting `sizeList.map is not a function`  - https://codesandbox.io/s/form-2-add-more-size-similar-to-s0-q27oi?file=/demo.js

Comment: You have 3 buttons that need handlers, addColor, addSize, removeSize, and you need 3 text input handlers for size, color, and stocks. The strategy for each one is to create a new sizeList such that the proper field on the correct element in the list is updated, and everything else stays the same.

Comment: The 3 text input handlers you mean are those something like `handleChange`?